# Jenkins: How to use choice parameter in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My example:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(
        name: 'myParameter',
        choices: "Option1\Option2",
        description: 'interesting stuff' )
  }
}
```

outputs with error:

```
"  unexpected char: '\'  " on the line with "choices" "
```

Following these instructions: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines

Any idea or advice on what I do wrong?

Comment: You are missing newline character to separate the choices - `"Option1\nOption2"`.

Comment: thank you @mkobit that was an issue indeed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `\n` instead of `\`.
See this code:

```
  pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(
        name: 'myParameter',
        choices: "Option1\nOption2",
        description: 'interesting stuff' )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any plans to support dynamic parameters so I can populate the choices from the results of a call out to a shared library?  This critical feature is currently missing.

Answer (score 26):

The documentation for declarative jenkins pipelines says:

A choice parameter, for example:

```
pipeline { 
    .....
     parameters { 
       choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: ['one', 'two', 'three'], description: '') }
```

First one is the default value

Comment: Link to the related documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Answer (score 10):

The arguably most elegant way to separate choices is by using an array like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(
      name: 'Env',
      choices: ['DEV', 'QA', 'UAT', 'PROD'],
      description: 'Passing the Environment'
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage('Environment') {
      steps {
        echo " The environment is ${params.Env}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer to improve readability. Also, please add some explanation about the code you posted.

Comment: has this change? i get 'Expected a block for parameters ' exception when trying to add multiple parameters